# Use one c source code file in multiple projects

Tags: c, makefile

I've written several c text processing functions that I've placed in a the files: string_functions.c and string_functions.h.

I was using these functions for one project and that worked out well.  Now I want to use these same functions in a completely different project at the same time.  I'm using gcc in Debian.

Is there a good way to use the same c source code in multiple projects at the same time.  The projects are in different sub-directories with the same parent directory.

How do I structure the make files to do this?

Or do I just place a copy of the string_functions.c(h) in both projects.  This seems like it would make it harder to maintain the source code.

Comment: If you're not used to writing makefiles, I'd recommend you [SCons](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html). It is a much easier to use build system, and you  use it to define separate build descriptions for your main projects and your shared code.

Comment: If the usage and compilation settings are the same, the single source should be compiled to a static or shared library. It is feasible (and in fact I have had happen) that a single source files is compiled in to different projects of entirely different nature (one 32bit DLL, another 64bit unrelated EXE), In such a case, including the same source *as source* in both is warranted. You simply have to remember the intermediate output (the object code) for that shared source file **must** be kept separate as multiple outputs (one for each project) will be generated, and they are **not** compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is to build your C files (.h and .c) into a shared library.

There are many tutorials available on how to do this with gcc; one is [at this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)

Once the shared library is built, you can then link it into many other projects.

Briefly, these are the steps.

Ensure your string_functions.c includes string_functions.h and builds, of course.

Then compile position independent (that's what -fPIC is for)

```
$gcc -Wall -fPIC -c string_functions.c
```

Finally build your shared library like this

```
$gcc -shared -o my_stringfunctions.so string_functions.o
```

To link to your new shared library from some other program,  ensure that whatever directory
you put it in is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Then you may link using something like

```
$gcc  my_otherprogram.c -L/path/to/my/lib -lmy_stringfunctions
```

As pointed out, one should put include files (.h) used by a shared library in some directory path, and add the location to the include search path using the -I option:

```
$gcc  my_otherprogram.c -I/path/to/include/files -L/path/to/my/lib -lmy_stringfunctions
```

Comment: This is fine but it's only half of the answer ... you should also talk about putting the header file in a common location and including it with -I.

Answer (score 0):

If this is how your directory looks:

```
/parent
    /project1
        ...
        string_functions.h
        string_functions.c
    /project2
        ...
        string_functions.h
        string_functions.c
```

Then all you have to do is store it in a common location, and then point to that location when building your code. This is the standard way of doing it for custom installed libraries in `/opt/`, for example.

Hence, one suggestion is to do your directory structure like this:

```
/parent
    /include
        string_functions.h
        string_functions.c
    /project1
        ...
    /project2
        ...
```

And when building your respective projects, you include that search path when compiling (using the `-I` flag):

```
gcc mainfile.c -I/parent/include <other options>
```